# Change name of OS in linux mint 20.1

Tags: linux-mint, grub

I want to change the name of the OS so in the grub menu it only shows Linux mint and not Linux Mint xfce 20.1 to make it as clean as posible where can i change the name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not know Mint, but since based on Ubuntu, should be similar.

To change name/label in menu change info in quotes to whatever makes sense to you, # comments out old entry or delete that line, edit at will & then update grub menu with new settings:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

#GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='Mint'
sudo update-grub
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Comment: Thanks that works